# Why enumerating through an object gives an undefine?

Tags: jquery, jstree

When attempting to enumerate through the data object's value, its gives a value of undefined for all of its properties but getting the value without enumerating gives a value of string data (working)...

Create the jstree node without no problems...

```
 $("#treeFile1").jstree("create", null, "outside", { "attr" : { "rel" : "folder" }});
```

Listening for the event above

```
 $("#treeFile1").bind("create.jstree", function(event,data)
 {      
alert(data.args.toSource()); // gives a string output not defined
    alert(data.inst.toSource());

for(var prop in data)
{
     alert("Property name is: "+ prop + "  property value is: "+  data.prop);
         // gives each value as undefined, why is this?
}
     event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) instead of [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Dot_notation) to use `prop`'s *value* as the accessed property name:

```
alert("Property name is: "+ prop + "  property value is: "+  data[prop]);
```

MDN's documentation provides [a solid `for...in` example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Example).

Comment: +1; the fancy ES5 way: `Object.keys(data).forEach(function(p){alert(data[p])});` saves the check for enumerable properties of the object.

Comment: Indeed, but of course that's not supported in the ever-crappy older versions of IE.

Comment: True, but IE9 "already" is capable of this. So it won't be far since we can use this without problems.